# Error in exporting other language text as ???? in Tally data

Tags: node.js, xml, curl, encoding, tally

While exporting [Tally](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tally_Solutions) data from Tally, it supports multilanguage texts, but while executing an XML file from another source like, a cmd or [Postman](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/postman/info) request, the **other** language texts are returned like `?` symbols.

My code is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <ENVELOPE>
  <HEADER>
   <TALLYREQUEST>ExportData</TALLYREQUEST>
   </HEADER>
   <BODY>
   <EXPORTDATA>
   <REQUESTDESC>
   <REPORTNAME>TNetSA LedgerSalesorders</REPORTNAME>
   <STATICVARIABLES>
   <SVCURRENTCOMPANY>${companyName}</SVCURRENTCOMPANY>
   <SVFROMDATE>${fromDate}</SVFROMDATE>
   <SVTODATE>${toDate}</SVTODATE>
   <SVEXPORTFORMAT>$$SysName:XML</SVEXPORTFORMAT>
   </STATICVARIABLES>
   </REQUESTDESC>
   </EXPORTDATA>
   </BODY>
   </ENVELOPE>
```

**Post request**
**UTF-8**

Header=> Content-Type:application/xml; charset=utf-8

https://i.stack.imgur.com/T9WDW.png

**UTF-16**

Header=> Content-Type:application/xml; charset=utf-16

https://i.stack.imgur.com/S4J7H.png

**Using Curl commands**

```
  curlcommand = cd  C:\Users\..\Data\ && curl -H "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8" localhost:9001 --data @Basic\I_SPND.xml
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/PJpAK.png

**Node.js:**

```
const asynchronousProcess = () => {
    var inputFilename = Path + 'I_SPND.xml'; // Path of the stored above XML code
    fs.writeFile(inputFilename, values, 'utf8', function (err) {
        if (err) {
            return console.log(err);
        }
    });
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let cmd = curlcommand; // The above mentioned curl command
        exec(cmd, (error, stdout, stderr) => {
            if (error) {
                reject(error);
            }
            resolve(stdout ? stdout : stderr);
        });

    });
}
```

For example: If PartyLedgerName is in another language text result will be?

While running on the Tally developer tool, it is supporting multilanguage texts, but on posting a request or using a [curl](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CURL) command means it is not supporting it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to *install* "node-fetch": "^3.2.10"

**Sample Node.js Snippet**

```javascript
import fetch from 'node-fetch';

let SourceXml = "<ENVELOPE Action=\"\"><HEADER><VERSION>1</VERSION><TALLYREQUEST>EXPORT</TALLYREQUEST><TYPE>COLLECTION</TYPE><ID>CUSTOMLEDGERCOL</ID></HEADER><BODY><DESC><STATICVARIABLES /><TDL><TDLMESSAGE><COLLECTION ISMODIFY=\"No\" ISFIXED=\"No\" ISINITIALIZE=\"No\" ISOPTION=\"No\" ISINTERNAL=\"No\" NAME=\"CUSTOMLEDGERCOL\"><TYPE>LEDGER</TYPE><FETCH>   NAME </FETCH><FILTERS>LedgFilter</FILTERS></COLLECTION><SYSTEM TYPE=\"Formulae\" NAME=\"LedgFilter\">$Name = \"Test Party_altered\"</SYSTEM></TDLMESSAGE></TDL></DESC></BODY></ENVELOPE>"
let buffer = Buffer.from(SourceXml, 'utf16le')

function test() {
    fetch('http://localhost:9000', {
        method: 'POST', body: buffer, headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/xml; charset=utf-16',
        },
    })
        .then(res => res.blob())
        .then(async data => {
            const buffer = Buffer.from(await data.arrayBuffer());
            console.log(buffer.toString('utf16le'));
        })
}
test()
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: Please review *[Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/)* (e.g., *"Images should only be used to illustrate problems that* ***can't be made clear in any other way,*** *such as to provide screenshots of a user interface."*) and [do the right thing](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74135694/edit) (it covers answers and program output as well). Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It’s not about language; it’s about the encoding used in Tally to send the response.

If you are sending a request in [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) encoding, you will get response in UTF-8 only.

In order to get data from correctly, use [UTF-16](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16) encoding.

If you are using any programming language to send request, then you can encode the request XML to UTF-16, then you will get response correctly.

**Postman response with UTF-8 encoding**

[image: Postman without encoding]

**Sending UTF-16 encoded request from postman**

Save the XML content you are sending in XML in a text file and while saving, use UTF-16 encoding:

[image: XML save with encoding]

**Configuring Postman**

In [Postman](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/postman/info), under the body tab, select the binary tab and select the file you saved in the earlier step.

In the headers tab

Add a new Header

Key - Content-Type Value - application/xml; charset=utf-16

[image: Postman result]

Comment: Yes UTF-16 is not working in postman, Any possible way to encode it on postman

Comment: I tried the previous method but getting response like this only.. <RESPONSE>Unknown Request, cannot be processed</RESPONSE>

Comment: previous method means, using any intermediary lang, if yes then post what code you are using

Comment: Now kindly check the above query

Comment: Content type header should have 'application/xml; charset=utf-16', response is also utf-16,
In node js when you are writing file use utf-16 encoding

Comment: Hello sai vineeth, I'm still facing this issue

Comment: @Abisha I added code snippet in nodejs, and it's also working